# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_active_and_valid_themes() on wp-settings.php on line 477

Tags: wordpress

I have this error and I seems can't get any decent answer on the web. Your answers will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`wp_get_active_and_valid_themes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_active_and_valid_themes/). You'll see that it's a *private core function*, which means plugins and themes aren't supposed to use it. It's also defined on `wp-load.php`. This most likely indicates one of two things.

1) Your WP Installation isn't valid. Reinstall the most recent version of WordPress and it should fix itself.

2) If you're attempting to use WordPress functions outside of WordPress (for example, in a custom PHP file), you're not properly loading in `wp-load.php` with `require_once( 'path/to/your/wp-load.php' );`

Comment: I confirm. In my case this was caused by incomplete/mixed WP installation that included files from both older WP version and new 5.1 files. User tried to perform upgrade and later had to revert back from backup which also failed for some reason and resulted in some files being left from 5.1. Reuploading WP 5.1 fixed the issue. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

this just happened to several sites for me as well that were using WP Super Cache.  i just deactivated all plugins and the theme (via wp_options db table) and reactivated them and it was fixed. strange

Comment: I was not able to solve it by deactivating so I have to re install WP and go minor edits on the site. Next time if this occurs I will try the way you approach the problem rather than start and reinstall and go over again.